# Angular-UI-Bootstrap and UI-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Whats the difference between ***angular-ui-bootstrap*** and ***ui-bootstrap***?

Because when i did `bower install ui-bootstrap` many files came like **Dropdown,Accordian**.But no js link of main bootstrap and when i did `bower install angular-bootstrap`  only js i got.
i'm bit confused whether both are same or different or linked somehow...please help
how to use ui-bootstrap which has many plugins like accordian

Comment: `angular-bootstrap` is bower repository for `ui-bootstrap` and is updated with original code repo. I think the bower repos are created to get only required files in bower and not whole bunch of unwanted files used for dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is official documents page: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap

This is: How to install https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#installation

Install with NPM

```
$ npm install angular-ui-bootstrap
```

This will install AngularJS and Bootstrap NPM packages.

Install with Bower

```
$ bower install angular-bootstrap
```